# TS3 STATUS - ADD IN TD TAG

Tags: php, html, status

I don't know how to do it cause I don't understand much PHP, but I want to do this thing, i have this code in HTML:

```
<td class="servers" id="online">EXAMPLE ONLINE / OFFLINE FROM PHP</td>
```

I want to put in the < td > tag server status ONLINE / OFFLINE what I will get from my PHP code:

```
<?php
//Load Framework
require_once("libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php");

try {
//Connect
   $ts3 = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://serveradmin:querypassword@ts3.domain:10011/?server_port=9987");

//Server Status
echo "ONLINE";
}
catch(Exception $e) {
//Errors (No connection)
echo "OFFLINE";
}

?>
```

How to do it, please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//Load Framework
require_once("libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php");

try {
//Connect
   $ts3 = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://serveradmin:querypassword@ts3.domain:10011/?server_port=9987");

//Server Status
$result = "ONLINE";
}
catch(Exception $e) {
//Errors (No connection)
$result = "OFFLINE";
}

echo "<td class='servers' id='$result'>$result</td>";
?>
```